# Im trying to move an image, but is too big for my relative layout?

Tags: android, image, imageview, image-size

i want the image to be moved up but as you can see i cant go any higher on a relative layout.
its the perfect size so i dont want to shrink the image.
xml code:

```
 android:id="@+id/imageView1"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button3"
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/top"
```

here a link to my screenshot: http://tinypic.com/r/fuv0i/6

Answer (score 1):

remove the following code set visibility, then you can move the imageview anywhere in the screen through the code

```
 android:layout_above="@+id/button3"
 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
```

Set Visibility,

```
 android:setVisibility="gone"
```

Comment: tried using the code above but when i got to move the image it automatically wants to lock into place, and bring me to square one. is there anyway to make the green box around it shrink?